# How to divide each value in a pivot table generated in R with grand total?

Tags: r

The pivot table was generated using the below R script. In the script the two columns are basement and style. This indicates for which style(0,1,2) there are basement present in house or not(basement being 0 or 1)

```
library(pivottabler)
#qpvt(myData, "style", "basement", "n()")
pt <- PivotTable$new() 
pt$addData(myData)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("basement")
pt$addRowDataGroups("style")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalHouses",summariseExpression="n()")
pt$renderPivot()
```

|  | 0 | 1 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14 | 25 | 39 |
| 1 | 0 | 25 | 25 |
| 2 | 3 | 41 | 44 |
| Total | 17 | 91 | 108 |

Is there way that all the cells in the pivot table generated above is divided with the grand total, which is 108 in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your code to get the percentages....

`pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Percentage", caption="%", format="%.1f %%", basedOn="TotalHouses", type="function", calculationFunction=getPercentageOfAllCategories)`

Can't check because no raw data provided.
See here: [pivottabler Counting Small Ns and Row Percentages (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349307/pivottabler-counting-small-ns-and-row-percentages-r)